# Change value of color channels to specific value from numpy array of image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to convert PNG images (3 channels [RGB]) into numpy array. If the color channels value is [255 255 255], then the array value should be 0. If the color channels value is [87 136 54], the array value should be 1. And if the color channels value is [70 105 41], then the array value should be 2.

This is my code to convert PNG into numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

I = np.asarray(Image.open('Image.png'))
print(I)
```

Output:

```
[[[255 255 255] [87 136 54] [87 136 54] ... [255 255 255] [70 105 41] [255 255 255]]
 [[255 255 255] [255 255 255] [87 136 54] ... [87 136 54] [87 136 54] [255 255 255]]
 [[255 255 255] [87 136 54] [255 255 255] ... [255 255 255] [255 255 255] [255 255 255]]
 ...
 [[70 105 41] [70 105 41] [255 255 255] ... [70 105 41] [87 136 54] [255 255 255]]
 [[87 136 54] [87 136 54] [255 255 255] ... [87 136 54] [70 105 41] [255 255 255]]
 [[255 255 255] [255 255 255] [255 255 255] ... [255 255 255] [255 255 255] [255 255 255]]]
```

My expected output:

```
[[0 1 1 ... 0 2 0]
 [0 0 1 ... 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [2 2 0 ... 2 1 0]
 [1 1 0 ... 1 2 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of your code did you expect to convert the values to 0, 1, and 2?!

Comment: Did you try using the `==` operator to implement the logic?

Comment: If I use that operator, it will require high processing time. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Use a smaller image if you want less processing

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.apply_along_axis()` with `axis=2` could achieve what you want.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

I = np.asarray(Image.open('Image.png'))


# define the mapping
mapping = np.array([[255, 255, 255],
                    [87, 136, 54],
                    [70, 105, 41]])

# define conversion function
def convert(pix, cmap):
    return np.argmax((pix == cmap).all(axis=1))

# apply convert function along axis=2
I = np.apply_along_axis(convert, 2, I, mapping)
```

Note that `convert()` function assumes that every possible color from the array `I` is defined in the `mapping` array. If that is not the case, the function needs to be modified, for example, to replace unknown colors to a fixed index value.